# I keep getting this error: Illegal assignment from LIST<Event__c> to String

Tags: apex

Here's my code:

```
public class MySessionRequestController{
transient public String sessions;
public String getSessions(){
    if (sessions == null){
        sessions = [SELECT name, Sponsor_Name__c, Start_Date__c, Event_Location__c, Event_Venue__c, DT_Facilitators_and_Support_Team__c, Goals__c FROM Event__c];
    }
    return sessions;
}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to deal with this error?

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty here is that you are trying to assign a List to a variable you have declared as a string. A SOQL query, such as `[Select name, Sponsor_Name__c.... from Event__c]` will return a list of SObjects- in this case your custom Event__c object. What precisely is your intended output? If you want, for instance, a list of names you could assemble them by iterating through the list produced by the SOQL query and appending names to the string.

Alternately, if what you really want is just a list of events, you can change the type of your Sessions variable and the return type of 'getSessions' to `Event__c[]` or, equivalently, `List<Event__c>`.

Comment: So what I really want is to get the integer value of the months out of the Start_Date__c portion of the query in order to sort them into a rolling calendar that automatically puts the events into the proper month no matter what the year is. So my problem is getting these integers out of the query and the month function that is built in to apex was having the same issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: So, if you take my second suggestion and get a list of Events, you could then iterate through the list of events, and for each Event__c, look at the Start_Date__c and grab the month out of that. Something along the lines of
`for(Event__c e : sessions){ Integer month = e.Start_Date__c.month();}`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

Your query

`[SELECT name, Sponsor_Name__c, Start_Date__c, Event_Location__c, Event_Venue__c, DT_Facilitators_and_Support_Team__c, Goals__c FROM Event__c]`

returns a list of Event__C records which you assigning to a string.

**Solution:**

change this

`transient public String sessions;`  ( not sure why you need transient key, assuming you know what you transient means I am leaving it as such) to

```
transient public List<event__c> sessions;
```

and

```
public String getSessions(){public String getSessions(){ to 


public List<event__c> getSessions(){public String getSessions(){
```

and

Instead of checking if sessions is null create a constructor for the class and create a new list of Events__c

```
public class MySessionRequestController{
public MySessionRequestController(){
sessions = new List<event__c>();
}
}
```

**Note:** This does not garuntee your issue will be solved, you might be rendering a string in your VF page. Paste your VF page too, looking at the context in which Sessions is being used will help us guide you better.